# how to change grails 2.3.8 version to grails 2.1.1

Tags: grails

I installed Grails 2.4.0 but my current project needs Grails 2.1.1 version So is it possible to change from Grails 2.4.0 to Grails 2.1.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WARNING: The gvmtool dot net URL now redirects to a spam site. A check of archive.org shows it previously [redirected to SDKMan](https://web.archive.org/web/20170603005954/http://gvmtool.net/).*

Are you using **Linux or Mac OS X**? If so, definitely look into using [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/). You can install different versions of Grails on one machine and easily switch between them by running a command like `gvm use grails 2.1.1`.

If you are on **Windows** then you can use GVM with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or you could try [Posh-GVM](https://github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm), which is GVM for PowerShell.

Comment: I am a windows user which GVM shall I use? I need change the or switching between different versions of Grails in Groovy/Grails suite tool

Comment: I would probably go with Posh GVM. It won't require you to install Cygwin and learn how to use that. You will just need to use install GVM via PowerShell and then use PowerShell to execute any Grails commands/install new versions of Grails.

Comment: I could not find a way to install posh-gvm on windows 10. "Install-Module posh-gvm" fails with "No match was found" and the "via short script" method gives "SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException", even running as admin

Answer (score 3):

**Mac/Linux**
The easiest way to install Grails 3 on Mac and Linux is to use SDKMAN! which we used in the previous section to install Java.

```
# Install SDKMAN if you haven't
$ curl -s get.sdkman.io | bash
# Install Grails 3
$ sdk install grails 3.3.8
```

To verify Grails was installed successfully:

```
$ grails -v
| Grails Version: 3.3.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.15
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_181
```

You can also use SDKMAN to switch between Grails versions:

```
# Easily switch between different versions:
$ sdk use grails 3.2.11
```

To learn more check out the SDKMAN usage guide http://sdkman.io/usage.html

**Windows**
Posh-GVM (PowerShell GVM) is the Windows equivalent to SDKMAN (SDKMAN’s original name was GVM - Groovy Version Manager). A few things to note on a Windows system is to keep any whitespace out of your file path and be careful of file and directory length limits. I recommend keeping your Grails app source at C:\source to avoid most issues.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) is a great tool for installing and switching between different versions of Grails